# How to use enum type on the view?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following controls:

```
<smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" filterType="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.FilterType.single" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
```

Property `filterType` expects an `enum` type - [API reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.FilterType).

The question is, am I using `enum` correctly? If yes, why does WEB IDE still have an error:

[image]

Comment: As [akudev mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104609/5846045), enum values can be used directly in XML by assigning the last part of the full name: `sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.FilterType.single` --> `"single"` (case sensitive!). But again, it's not always the case as you can see in this issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2169. In cases like this, if applying the last part doesn't work, you'll need to look at the source code of the enum type definition for the real value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine for me. Hope this helps.

```
 filterType="single"
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct for this specific case.

In general, the enum value (the last segment of the full name) can be used just as a string. This also works in JS code (string instead of enum object).
Note that, unlike this one, most enum valuess start with an uppercase letter.